# How can I make an object move across my screen gradually using a loop in Lua and Corona Labs SDK

Tags: android, loops, lua, crash, coronasdk

I'm making a game that has obstacles which the player must jump over. I'm using the Corona Labs Simulator to run it but every time I do either the obstacle gets half way across the screen instantly and stops or the whole thing just crashes. Here is my code:

```
    function obstacles()
        loop = 2000
        while loop > 0 do
            obstacle:translate( -1, 0 )
            if obstacle.x > 0 then
                loop = loop - 1
            else
                loop = 2000
                obstacle:translate( display.contentWidth, 0 )
            end
        end
    end
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Its important to understand that Corona SDK is an event driven system. There really isn't a game loop. Code executes so fast you can't use structures like loops to move things.

As mentioned above, the transition library (transition.to for instance) can move an object over time.

The closest thing to a game loop is to create a function and attach it to the Runtime object using the "enterFrame" event. Every frame (either 30 times per second or 60 times per second), this function will be called. It's not going to be precisely 30 or 60 times per second because it make take too much time doing other work to give you the full frame rate. If you want to use an enterFrame listener:

```
local function doSomethingEachFrame( event )
    -- put code here you want to execute over time.
    -- just remember it fires a lot...
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", doSomethingEachFrame )
```

If you need to stop it, then you would do:

```
Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", doSomethingEachFrame )
```

Answer (score 1):

Corona SDK provides tools to do exactly that. Rather than using a loop, use [transition library](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/transition/to.html):

```
transition.to(target, params)
```

where target is your **obstacle** object, and in params, you can specify x position, time etc.

Comment: Thanks so much. That part of the game is done. The last bit is the scoring. Is there a way to end the game if an object is touching a certain colour?

Comment: Of course @Mitra0000. I'd suggest asking a new question for that though.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a few sources of weirdness regarding where things appear on-screen. I'd put `obstacle` at (0,0) with no movement at all and make sure I understand both the coordinate system of the parent, and the [`anchorX`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/anchorX.html) and [`anchorY`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/anchorY.html) of `obstacle` before trying to animate it.

I assume there's other code outside the block you've included, but I think you can make the movement logic simpler, and you'll thank yourself later (this isn't perfect, but you get the idea):

```
-- set initial position
obstacle.x = display.contentWidth

-- define per-frame movement logic
local moveObstacle = function(event)
    obstacle.x = obstacle.x - 1

    if obstacle.x < 0 then
        obstacle.x = display.contentWidth
    end
end

-- run that logic once every frame
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", moveObstacle)
```